# Could not be found any android.support.v4.widget in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-support-library

In Android Studio I get errors when changing the layout:

> The following classes could not be found:
>
> ```
> - android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
> ```

or

> The following classes could not be found:
>
> ```
> - android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
> ```

and it does not display any layout. I have set Gradle like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraryfab')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/jetbrains-annotations.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/pinchzoom.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3-with-sources.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

Android Support Library is installed. Before this project is importing from Eclipse Project. If I create a new project with Navigation Drawer Activity (use `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`), it looks like it works and displays the layout.

Comment: Go to SDK manager and download Android Support Library and see

Comment: @Nabin Android Support Library have installed sir..

Comment: Did you run `grade clean` ?

Comment: @EllieZou Sync gradle or clean project  ? yes , I did both .. I have restart my Android Studio too ..

Comment: Invalidate android studio caches and restart hop this will done . if not then re install android SDK and android supporting libs

Comment: @sourabhdevpura i have did sir, but if  test create new project with Navigation Drawer Activity , it's look works and display layout.... Before My Project is importing from Eclipse Project

Comment: Try to run `gradle assemble`. Check if you have some errors. Do you have this error when you display the layout or when you try to run your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Issue From Version of ANdroid Studio. To fix it :

1. Install Last Update Android Studio (current Android STudio Beta 1.3 Canary Chanel)
2. Invalidate/Restart

Answer (score 0):

Check the path of **android SDK** in android studio . cos as i fill . in your eclipse project **android SDK** path is **Different then  android studio** . so when you create new project it work perfect . but when you import your project it target the SDK on the path where support lib not located

[image]

I hop this will help you

Comment: android SDK path same as In eclipse. i set in one directory path :(